# Pass arguments to helpers in Spacebars Template Inclusion

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Say I have a template with a template inclusion

```
<template name="Profile_Page">
    {{> Text_Form_Control value=helper_function}}
</template>
```

I want to return an array from my helper function and access specific indexes depending on when the helper function is called. However, I cannot simply type helper_function[0] to access the 1st slot in the array. How would one normally access the index of an array if it is passed back from a helper function?

Comment: Try `helper_function.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally if a helper returns an array you want spacebars to iterate over it with an `{{#each foo}}` or `{{#Each bar in foo}}`

Otherwise if you want your helper to return different single pieces of data, pass in an argument:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  myHelper(index) {
    var myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
    return myArray[index];
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="Profile_Page">
  {{> Text_Form_Control value=(helper_function 0)}}
</template>
```